# AS3: Get URL name

Tags: actionscript-3, url, embed

Trying to get the current URL of the website I have posted the flash object in, without using Javscript or ExternalInterface calls.

e.g.

Website Im posting in is http://some.forum.com

Website of swf is http://uploaded.to/site/of/object.swf

In my post at some.forum.com I include in the post:

> [flash=100,100]http://uploaded.to/site/of/object.swf[/flash]

Unfortunately it keeps returning the url of website I initially uploaded to, and not the current forum I am linking it in.

Current used methods are:

> var urlname:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
>
> trace(urlname.domain());

and

> var urlName:String = this.loaderInfo.url;
>
> trace(urlName)

Both returning  uploaded.to/site/of/object.swf, and not some.forum.com

How do I get my desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it applies to your scenario but have you tried BrowerManager: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64e50-7ff8.html

Something like

```
var browserManager:BrowserManager = BrowserManager.getInstance();
trace(browserManager.url);
```

Comment: Hmm well that's a flex class and I'll need the swc to be able to import it into flash

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Well I've found a small workaround: Referrer.

All I need to do is get the swf to request another website that performs some javascript or php to return the URL of the referrer website.

```
var textLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader()
var textReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://my.site.com/findReferrer.html");
textLoader.load(textReq);
textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, trace(textLoader.data);
```

Unfortunately referrer is purely browser dependent and often doesn't work for https. 
So back to square one..